# WinForms app trying to install Framework, even though it exists

Tags: .net, winforms, windows-installer

I have a .Net WinForms app that targets Framework 4.0.
I'm trying to install the app on a PC that does not have internet access, but running it, I get the error below.

An error occurred downloading the following resource:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=182805

I have downloaded and installed the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (Standalone Installer) from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=24872), but my app still tries to download the Framework.  Seems like it does not see the 1 that I installed?

(I created the setup files with the VS2012 Publish Wizard)

Comment: Does your application target the Client Profile version of framework? (Properties on your porject file combobox Target Framework should say '.Net Framework Client Profile')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto Project Properties and Change Framework .net framework 4.0 Client Profile to .net framework 4.0

Comment: Yeah, I missed that.  My project can't be Client Profile 4, but I've downloaded the full .Net Framework 4 and that works.

Comment: Welcome Feel Free to Ask Questions... :)